# Does this sanitize have any XSS leaks in it

Tags: php, xss, sql-injection, sanitization

I want to make sure my sanitize doesnt have any leaks in it.
And also, im only outputting user-data within hardcoded p tags and h1 tags

eg : `<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($user_data); ?></p>`

So is this a safe way to protect me against XSS-injects.

First, im using this function to sanetize the data before it gets inserted into my DB, and while in my DB im using bind_param

```
function sanitize($str) {
   return strtolower(strip_tags(trim(($str))));
}

sanitize($user_data); - > then gets inserted into db
```

Then when I grap the data from the DB I am using this to show it.

```
<p> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($user_data); ?> </p>
```

So, is this a safe way to block any XSS?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, when Im inserting text from a textarea im using this: $txt = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['freetext'])); then simpy showing it by <p><?php echo $txt; ?></p>

Comment: As a side note: If you are escaping HTML attributes that are delimited by single quotes, make sure to set `ENT_QUOTES`.

Comment: BTW: Why are you stripping tags before inserting to the db?

Comment: @luiscubal do u mean if I use " '.$foo.' " ? 
I read this in the manual:

<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; 
?>

Comment: Is it a security risk if I **only** use htmlspecialchars() ?
Without ENT_QUOTES etc

Comment: If you do something like `<something attr='<?php echo htmlspecialchars(...); ?>'>`, then yes. Imagine the input is `foo' onload='maliciousjs()`. The result would be `<something attr='foo' onload='maliciousjs()'>` which is definitely bad. ENT_QUOTES escapes the `'` chars. (Interestingly, by default PHP uses ENT_COMPAT which escapes `"` correctly and only fails for `'`. Why? No idea. But using ENT_QUOTES never hurts.)

Comment: Thanks, so if I am using href='' I should add ENT_QUOTES, but if I am using href="" I shouldnt add ENT_QUOTES since its double quotes?

Comment: Always use ENT_QUOTES. ENT_QUOTES may or may not be necessary depending on the situation, but it is never harmful. So if you always use it you're safe and don't need to worry "wait was it against double or single quotes that PHP protected by default?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a security standpoint, there is no need to use your sanitize function as long as you escape / process your data correctly for the medium you are outputting to:

- Using `htmlspecialchars()` is all that is needed for output to html;
- Use `json_encode` if you need to output to javascript;
- Use prepared statements with bound variables for your database;
- etc.

Comment: little doubt.. he already using strip_tags then is it necessary to use htmlspecialchars ? Vice versa whether he need to use strip_tags ?

Comment: @user1844933 Frankly, I don't see the point of using strip_tags. htmlspecialchars will convert `<` to `&lt;` anyway, so the tags can't do anything.

Comment: @user1844933 Yes, there can be `<`, etc. signs in the texts as well that the browser can interpret as the start of a tag.

Comment: Is it a security risk if I **only** use htmlspecialchars() ?
Without ENT_QUOTES etc

Comment: @user2722667 That depends, if you are echoing out values for tag attributes and use single quotes to quote them, not encoding the user input could affect your html.